# how can we manage multiple user....in cacheManager

Tags: java, jpa

```
entityManager = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
UsersModel user = entityManager.find(UsersModel.class,User_Id);
cacheManager = CacheManager.getInstance();
cacheManager.cacheObject("user", user);
```

This is how I keep user details in cache, and I will retrieve using:

```
UsersModel user = (UsersModel)cacheManager.retriveObject("user");
user.getUserID();
```

But the problem arises when multiple user login, I will get only one user information.

I tried keeping `userID` in cache Key, but while retrieving record I need to know the key.

So, anybody know best way to solve this?

And I am using `Strust2` framework....

```
Hashtable<CacheKey, Object> cacheManager = new Hashtable<CacheKey,Object>();
```

Here the scenario when user1 Login,i put user1 object in cache...

cacheManager.cacheObject("user", user);

After Login Success User1 Click on Account Info where i have to fetch current User Details...

UsersModel user = (UsersModel)cacheManager.retriveObject("user");

user.getUserID();

user.getName();

At the same time when user2 Login...it will override the cache....user2 details is stored now....so when user1 will click again on AccInfo he will get User2 info...i just need to keep the corresponding user_id till he Logout...

Comment: You could store a Set<UsersModel> instead of a single object in the CacheManager.

Comment: Do you mean an example like this:   "Set<UsersModel> set = (Set<UsersModel>)cacheManager.retrieveObject("users"); for(UsersModel model: set) {...}"

Comment: Care to mention *which* CacheManager you're using here? EHCache? some other? and then perhaps tag your question as that

Comment: you can see my question...i have updated...and I am using HASHTABLE

Comment: (java.util.)Hashtable has no such method "retrieveObject" ...

Comment: Sir i am using CacheKey(java.util)then                              public Object retriveObject(String key) {
  CacheKey cacheKey = new CacheKey(key);
  try {
   if (cacheManager.containsKey(cacheKey)) {
    return cacheManager.get(cacheKey);
   }
  } catch (NullPointerException e) {
   System.out.println("Key not exists");
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CacheManager is a singleton which means it is shared between requests. What you are currenly doing is overwriting `user` cache entry every time for all sessions.
You could try to bind new CacheManager instance to session scope, but it is quite expensive to spawn CacheManager for each user separately.

I would do that this way: just keep `userId` in session and then

```
cacheManager.cacheObject("user/" + userId, user);
```

and

```
UsersModel user = (UsersModel)cacheManager.retriveObject("user/" + userId);
```

Keep in mind that object may be removed from cache so you need to eventually query for it again.

Comment: If you are using Struts 2 check this way http://www.splinter.com.au/how-to-use-sessions-with-struts-2/ . Once you have access to your `userId` you can pass it to your data access methods.